# Laravel can't get param header in request with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3

I'm working on a Laravel project (an API) and I have a problem with a custom param in the request header.

I need to send a token in the request header, so I just add a param `api_token` in my request.

When I am on my local configured with `apache2`, I can in Laravel get my header request param with `$request->header('api_token')`, but when I tr on my server configured with `nginx`, I always get `null`

For me, there is a problem with nginx and header request, what can I do ?

Any ideas ? Maybe it's not from nginx...

Comment: Laravel uses `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` `headers` collection to get header params. Ask your question with symfony component related tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because by default Nginx does not allow header with an underscore. You can simply update your header parameter to `api-token`:

```
$request->header('api-token');
```

Or you can configure your Nginx configuration to allow header with an underscore. Somewhere between your `server` block, add `underscores_in_headers` directive like this:

```
server {
    ...
    underscores_in_headers on;
    ...
}
```

Also don't forget to reload your Nginx configuration. Read more about this `underscores_in_headers` directive [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers).

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, for days I spent on this. Apparently this is the way.

Comment: Something so simple can drive one crazy :)